# Only update last row of an user entry

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-update, subquery

I have this query:

```
UPDATE uren_registratie SET
                        uren_eind = '".$add_uren_einde."'
                        WHERE user_id = '".$add_user_id."'
```

The table has on ID column that is updated +1 with each entry.

This is query is updating the fields where `user_id` matches. But I want only the last entry with that `user_id` to be updated. How to achieve this, in this query?
Or is the only way to use an `Select` query first to get the latest entry of that `user_id`?

Comment: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: How do you know which entry is the *last* one ?

Comment: also your code look prone to SQL injections.

Comment: I have only posted code of the query @Raymond Nijland. And everything is simple if you know how do it.

Comment: How do you identify the **last entry** Would that be the one with the highest `id`

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: I have posted only the coded needed to explain the question. Not the complete php script with all needed code to prevent SQL injection @tadman

Comment: If this was created with placeholder values you wouldn't need to show the "SQL injection prevention" code as it'd be obvious it's done correctly. This code could be wide open, we don't know. I've seen way too many cases where people think `trim` or `htmlspecialchars` can escape for SQL. It can't. It won't. Please don't take this lightly. A single mistake can be fatal for your site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the *last* entry of a given user is the one with the highest id, you use a correlated subquery, like :

```
UPDATE uren_registratie
SET uren_eind = '".$add_uren_einde."' 
WHERE user_id = '".$add_user_id."'
AND id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM uren_registratie WHERE user_id = '".$add_user_id."')
```